# Why does Wolfram Alpha get this binomial coefficient sum wrong?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, wolfram-alpha

The sum I want to evaluate is $\sum_{i=2}^m \binom{p-1}{i-2} * \binom{n-k}{m-i}$.
Here we have $p<k<=n$ and $m<=n$, all positive integers; I don't know how to communicate that to Wolfram Alpha though.

The correct answer (I think) is $\binom{n-k+p-1}{m-(k-p)+1}$.

Wolfram Alpha gives: $\frac{(-1)^m (-2 + k + m - n - p)!}{(-2 + m)! (k - n - p)!}$. Is this somehow equivalent to the correct answer? Why does it give factorials of negative integers? (admittedly, I didn't give Wolfram Alpha enough info to know these were negative integers, although $(k-n-p)!$ is pretty bad given I have $n-k$ as the top of a binomial coefficient in the sum).

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bi%3D2%7D%5Em+%28%28p-1%29+choose+%28i-2%29%29+*+%28%28n-k%29+choose+%28m-i%29%29

Comment: There is nothing wrong with negative numbers on *top* of a binomial coefficient if the bottom is a natural number.  For instance $\binom{n}2 = n(n-1)/2$ makes sense for any real value of $n$.  I agree that the use of factorials in the answer is odd, though.  I suspect if you convert it to a binomial coefficient then it will be equivalent via a simple identity like the ones on the bottom of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: If $m-2\geq p-1$ the sum becomes $$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\binom{p-1}j\binom{n-k}{m-j-2}=\binom{n+p-k-1}{m-2}$$  If $m-2< p-1$, you'll have to subtract the missing terms.